# C++ Order of Evaluation

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I'm trying to figure out if there's anything in the C++11 specification re. expected behavior for the following code ([GitHub link here](https://github.com/sxlijin/assorted-code-snippets/blob/e98a54618d102929fdc0b477e3bbba085002549e/language-semantic-examples/cpp/order_of_ops.cpp)):

```
struct Scalar {
    int data;

    Scalar(int x) : data(x) {}

    int get() {
        return data;
    }

    Scalar &square() {
        scale(data);
        return *this;
    }

    void scale(int rhs) {
        data *= rhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    Scalar v(3);

    v.square().scale(v.get());

    return v.data;
}
```

This comes up mostly because of the discovery that this does different things between `g++` and `clang++`:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ g++ -std=c++11 order_of_ops.cpp -o a.out && ./a.out; echo $?
27

$ clang++ -std=c++11 order_of_ops.cpp -o a.out && ./a.out; echo $?
81
```

The answer seems like it should be in § 5.2.2 and § 5.2.5 of [n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) but I'm having trouble tracking down something concrete.

Comment: `square()` and `get()` must be called before the call to `scale()`. But the relative order between them is unspecified by the standard.

Comment: I wouldn't dream of trying something like this. Undefined behaviour all the way.

Comment: When you want something concrete to present to students that you're TA'ing for, these are the kinds of questions you get to ask (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I read things correctly, the behaviour of your code is unspecified. N3337 for C++11 quotes:

> § 1.9 [intro.execution] / 15
>
> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...]
>   If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

but it follows with

> Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function
>   calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after
>   the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately
>   sequenced with respect to the execution of the called
>   function.<sup>9</sup>
>
> 9) In other words, function executions do not interleave with each
>   other.

and

> § 5.2.2 [expr.call] / 8
>
> [ *Note:* The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the
>   argument expressions are all unsequenced relative to one another. All
>   side effects of argument expression evaluations are sequenced before
>   the function is entered (see 1.9). *—end note* ]

So, your modification and unrelated read of `Scalar::data` are indeterminately sequenced.

That being said, it is likely to change and be well-defined in C++1z:

> N4606 § 5.2.2 [expr.call] / 5
>
> The *postfix-expression* is sequenced before each *expression* in the
>   expression-list and any default argument. The initialization of a
>   parameter, including every associated value computation and side
>   effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other
>   parameter.

Thus, in C++1z your `v.data` should be equal to 81 (if I read things correctly)

Comment: Pre-C++11, when we talked about sequence points, there was a sequence point before and after each function call. That would make the expression well defined, but with an unspecified result depending on the order of the calls.

Comment: @T.C. How is this relevant? Evaluation of function argument(s) and postfix expression designating the called function are both sequenced before execution of the function body. But they're not ordered relative to each other.

Comment: Ah, wait, I c/p'd the wrong quote. I meant "Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function." Now consider that there are three function calls in that statement.

Comment: @T.C. What about now?